# Intentando formatear resultado document.form.test.value

Tags: javascript

Utilizo esta función que formatea correctamente las operaciones de esta manera:

```js
// Formatea resultado del cálculo
function formatear(resultado) {
  return resultado.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
 return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
    });
}

function calculo(){
var input1 = document.getElementById("test").value;
var calculo = input1 * 950;

document.getElementById('total').value=formatear(calculo.toFixed(2)).substring(0,6).replace(",",".");
}
```

Necesito realizar la misma operación pero aquí **var importe=document.form.test.value * 950;** y no se me ocurre como aplicarlo de la misma forma, lo he intentado siguiendo la misma rutina sin resultado. Espero explicarme bien, agradezco un punto de luz para resolverlo. Gracias de antemano.

He intentado esto sin resultado:

```
var importe=document.form.test.value*950=formatear(importe.toFixed(2)).substring(0,6).replace(",",".");
```

Aqui lo dejo completo:

```js
// Compara los valores, metros cuadrados y total
document.form.onchange = function(){
 var metrosValor = document.getElementById("metros").value / 10;
 var totalValor = document.getElementById("total").value;
 
 if(parseInt(metrosValor)>parseInt(totalValor)){
   document.form.comparativa.value='' + metrosValor + ''; // Primer valor es mas grande que el segundo
 }else if(parseInt(metrosValor)<parseInt(totalValor)){
   document.form.comparativa.value='' + metrosValor + ''; // Primer valor es mas pequeño que el segundo
 }else{
   document.form.comparativa.value=''; // Si son iguales no muestra resultado.
 }
}

// Formatea resultado del cálculo
function formatea(resultados) {
  return resultados.replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
 return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
    });
}

// Muestra resultado del ahorro, antes de enviar formulario
function resultadoAhorro(){
var comparaMetrosTotal=document.form.comparativa.value;
var importe=document.form.comparativa.value * 950;
var ahorro=document.form.comparativa.value * 3.8 * 0.95;
var correo=document.form.email.value;

    document.getElementById('comparativa').value = comparaMetrosTotal + ' kWp'; 
    document.getElementById('importe').value = importe + ' €'; 
    document.getElementById('ahorro').value = ahorro + ' €' + '<hr>';

    document.getElementById('mensajeTotalAhorro').innerHTML='<h3 style="font-size:18px"><img src="img/potencia.png">Potencia ofertada: ' + comparaMetrosTotal + ' kWp</h3> <h3 style="font-size:18px"><img src="img/importe.png">Importe de la instalación: ' + importe + ' €</h3> <h3 style="font-size:18px"><img src="img/ahorro.png">Ahorros a futuro: ' + ahorro + ' €</h3> <p>El plazo de amortización para este tipo de instalaciones está entre 5 y 7 años, con una vida útil superior a 25 años. Más información en tu correo ' + correo + '</p><br>';
}
```

Me autorespondo de esta forma:

```
var importe=document.form.comparativa.value * 950; var formateaImporte =formatea(importe.toFixed(2)).substring(0,5).replace(",",".");
```